# Run scripts in a Node server

Tags: node.js

I have a server application using Node, and sometimes I need to run some script in it. Some examples of scenarios when this would be necessary:

- During development, I need to create many entries in the database to simulate an use case.
- In production, some bug happened and some information was not correctly stored in the DB, I may need to backfill it.

The way I know how do it in node is to deploy some instance of the server with an endpoint that contains the code to be run.

It is interesting to use the node server because it already has a lot of code that I can reused, for example DAO and safe create/delete funcitons.

Django has a interactive Python interpreter that does this job, but I do not know any similar way to it in Node.

Other strategies of doing this use cases are very welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question you are asking.  Are you asking if there is a specific way to do something?  Are you asking how to do a task without having to deploy to an endpoint?  Are you looking for how to use `npm run <script>`?  Please ask an exact question.

Comment: What is your definition of "script"? JavaScript file, bash/shell script, perl/python/php?

Comment: JS code to solve to run some procedure, but this this code is not a function that I could run from an endpoint. For example, fill a collumn of the database with some value. This can be a on time only, it does not make sense to build an endpoint, but I may want to use some DAOs. And mainly, run code to solve issues without need a new deploy.

Answer (score 0):

During development, you can just go with debugging, although that requires triggering a breakpoint. Alternatively, if it's just about your database, there are better external programs to interact with your database.

To actually answer your question: Node does have a [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module to run code and even a [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module to help writing custom REPLs. This does require some work to link up your APIs though, but doable.

As for how you actually interact with that REPL, there are several options. Using a raw socket (and Telnet), a [terminal on your site](https://xtermjs.org/) communicating over a WebSocket, a simple HTTP endpoint, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add scripts in your package.json to handle this with a path to the script. For example `"seed:db": "node ./src/seeder.js -i"`, `"drop:db": "node ./src/seeder.js -d"` where the `i` an `d` flags will be used to determine if i am inserting or deleting, and can be gotten with `process.argv[2]`

Comment: It seems promising, I will try this suggestion.